# Regex allowing word boundaries with lookahead and "."

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, word-boundary

I have the strings:

```
lorem ipsum Outer.Middle.Last dolor #1
lorem ipsum Outer.Middle dolor      #2
```

Currently I am using the regex `[[:<:]]Outer.Middle[[:>:]]` to try and match only string #2. However, this matches both strings #1 and #2 due to the naive boundaries.

I have attempted to do some sort of lookahead e.g. `[[:<:]]Outer.Middle(?!.)[[:>:]]`, but this is abysmally wrong.

The regex is necessary as I am using PostgreSQL and querying class names contained within text bodies.

Any solution or guidance to a solution would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
select * from my_table where my_col ~ '[[:<:]]Outer\\.Middle[[:>:]](?!\\.)'
```

The . characters should be escaped (otherwise they are treated as a wildcard matching any one character), and backslashes need escaping too.

This is also equivalent to:

```
select * from my_table where my_col ~ '[[:<:]]Outer[.]Middle[[:>:]](?![.])'
```

Comment: I removed my answer in favor of your better one.

Comment: Fantastic. Worked in my test cases. Thanks!